# How to access the root group object of h5 file

Tags: python, h5py

I want to get the root group object of the h5 file and add attributes to it, instead of creating a new subgroup like what I have now:

```
f = h5py.File("test.h5", "w")
grp = f.create_group("group1")
grp.attrs['att'] = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `h5py.File` [is its own root group](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html), so:

```
f.attrs['att'] = 0
```